# Google Spreadsheets IMPORTXML issue

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am facing a very strange problem with Spreadsheets and IMPORTXML.

I am developing this website in a Production/Staging environment and am generating an XML file to pull certain data from the database.

I have the following two URLs:

`https://www.volgshop.ch/xml/?t=xml&sfm=5&stm=5&cfm=4&ctm=4&st=1&ct=1` - which is for production

`https://volgshop.staging.wpengine.com/xml/?t=xml&sfm=5&stm=5&cfm=4&ctm=4&st=1&ct=1` - which is for staging

I am using the IMPORTXML function as follows:

`=IMPORTXML("https://volgshop.staging.wpengine.com/xml/?t=xml&sfm=5&stm=5&cfm=4&ctm=4&st=1&ct=1", "/*")`

And now comes the problem I'm facing: when I use the staging link, the data gets added correctly in the Spreadsheet, but when I use the production link, the data doesn't get added.

The script is the exact same.

The spreadsheet can be accessed here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/128EKD3a0srVIYbPw-iHxnmQaCGQm3_NMNAa5l9j2x4g/edit?usp=sharing

Has anyone faced something similar and can share a potential solution?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you check the log or execution script to see the error message? Can you share it to help us pin point the main issue.

Comment: That's the thing. I have no errors whatsoever. Here's a slightly better overview: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByGKTOcdBhTGMldPdDh4TW9jcDA/view

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by rewriting the URL with add_rewrite_rule, therefore my URLs have been rewritten to https://www.volgshop.ch/xml/5/5/4/4/1/1/

For all of you who use Wpengine as hoster, remember to uncache the XML page/URL you're using to display results, in my case: https://www.volgshop.ch/xml/